# How to pick random non-duplicating samples containing one element from each group?

Tags: python

Below is the list say `my_list`. Max items or max length of `my_list` could be 1 million.

```
[
    ['N1', 'C1'], 
    ['N2', 'C2'], 
    ['N3', 'C1'], 
    ['N4', 'C1'], 
    ['N5', 'C1'], 
    ['N6', 'C2'], 
    ['N7', 'C1']
]
```

I want to pick two samples from this list where the first one has `C1` and the second has `C2`. I will be picking the 2 samples 80 million times. In the given `my_list` the first item i.e the ones starting with `N*` will always be unique. Whereas, the final output pair I'm looking should not have same or duplicate pair repeating. I will always want a unique pair.

The output could be:

N1 and N2

OR

N2 and N1

OR

N6 and N7

I've used `random.sample()` with list previously, but in this case I'm not sure how to apply condition as the list element are separated by `,`.

Comment: The condition is applied to only the 2nd item of sublist?

Comment: How many C1 and C2 items do you have? Are they approximately equal or do you have many more of one than the other? Do you need to do this only once for the list or multiple times?

Comment: Can you explain why the output can't be N7 and N6 for example?

Comment: Yes, pick two first item samples - one whose 2nd item is `C` and the other whose 2nd item is `C2`.

Comment: @nonlinear That's right. Output could be N7 and N6. I've updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Do something radical - shuffle the list and then pack it into a dictionary based on the second item as a key. Last "man" standing wins

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - As mentioned there could be 1 million items in list. There are no fixed number on no. of C1 and C2. I will be picking 2 samples for 80 million times.  I've updated my question.

Comment: You want to pick two samples from a collection of 1 million items.... 80 million times?

Comment: If that's the case, I reckon `shuffle` will become really expensive. I'm just trying to clarify the scale here. I assume you can have duplicate pairs?

Comment: @roganjosh The pair could be `N6 and N7` or `N2 and N1`. Yes, I don't need duplicate pairs here.

Comment: I'm asking whether duplicate pairs are _permissible_. I can find a faster way than the other answers given, but not without the possibility of duplicate pairs in your 80 million samples

Comment: @roganjosh in the given `my_list` the first item i.e the ones starting with `N*` will always be unique. Whereas, the final output pair I'm looking should not have same or duplicate pair repeating. I will always want a unique pair.

Comment: That's an important constraint, and you should mention it in your question. Both answerers so far haven't known that. Also,  depending on the ratio of C1 to C2 items, it could in some circumstances be impossible. (Think of an extreme case: one C1 and 999,999 C2. In this case you could only get 999,999 unique matchings, or twice that since you seem to care about item order.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky - I've updated my question with the constraint.

Comment: @Viki, is `numpy` solution acceptable?

Comment: The fact remains that there might not always be 80 million unique pairs available. In such cases, do you want a smaller output list? Should it throw an error?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this multiple times for the same list, you could separate the list into groups and then select one from each group:

```
# This needs to be done once per my_list
groups = {}

for n, c in my_list:
    if c not in groups:
        groups[c] = []
    groups[c].append(n)

# this selects random elements from each group
result = tuple(random.choice(grp) for grp in groups.values())
```

For example, running the selection code 10 times gives:

```
for _ in range(10):
    # this selects random elements from each group
    result = tuple(random.choice(grp) for grp in groups.values())

    print(result)
```

```
('N5', 'N2')
('N7', 'N6')
('N5', 'N6')
('N7', 'N6')
('N4', 'N2')
('N5', 'N2')
('N1', 'N2')
('N7', 'N2')
('N1', 'N2')
('N1', 'N6')
```

---

This code can be put in a class to make it easier to use:

```
class GroupedSelect:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.groups = {}
        for n, c in my_list:
            if c not in self.groups:
                self.groups[c] = []
            self.groups[c].append(n)

    def select(self):
        return tuple(random.choice(grp) for grp in self.groups.values())


my_selector = GroupedSelect(my_list)
for _ in range(10):
    print(my_selector.select())
```

---

To prevent duplicates, you're going to have to keep track of which elements have already been selected. One way to do this would be to figure out how many elements the product of all groups contains, and return one of those in random order.

Upon creating the `GroupedSelect` object, we

- Figure out how many combinations we will have. This is simply the product of the lengths of all groups.
- Create a list of indices of that length. For example, if we have 5 objects in group 1 and 2 in group 2, we have 10 combinations, so `self._sel_indices` is `list(range(10))`. Then shuffle this list
- Every time `select()` is called, we `pop` the last element of this list. Since popping the last element of a list is O(1), this is not an expensive operation.

  - If no more indices exist, then we can either reshuffle or raise an error.
- The popped index is converted to the individual coordinates in the groups. The logic for this is identical to that of [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html).
- Return the element at these coordinates.

```
import random
from functools import reduce

class GroupedSelect:
    def __init__(self, my_list, raise_error=False):
        self.groups = {}
        self._raise_error = raise_error
        for n, c in my_list:
            if c not in self.groups:
                self.groups[c] = []
            self.groups[c].append(n)

        self._shape = tuple(len(grp) for grp in self.groups.values())
        self._reshuffle()

    def _reshuffle(self):
        n_indices = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, self._shape)
        
        # Create a list of all possible indices and shuffle it
        self._sel_indices = list(range(n_indices))
        random.shuffle(self._sel_indices)
        

    def select(self):
        try:
            # Get the next index to select
            index = self._sel_indices.pop()
        except IndexError as ex: 
            # If we've selected all possible indices, reshuffle everything and start over
            # or raise an error if needed
            if self._raise_error:
                raise RuntimeError("No more combinations to select") from ex
            self._reshuffle()
            index = self._sel_indices.pop()

        # Convert index to coordinates in each group
        coords = self._index_to_coords(index)
        
        # Select the correct value from each group and return it
        return tuple(grp[coord] for grp, coord in zip(self.groups.values(), coords))
     
    def _index_to_coords(self, index):
        # This function is a pure-python implementation of numpy.unravel_index
        coords = []
        for ss in reversed(self._shape):
            index, cc = divmod(index, ss)
            coords.append(cc)
        return coords[::-1]
```

To use this class such that it will throw an error after it runs out of combinations, do:

```
my_selector = GroupedSelect(my_list, True)
for _ in range(12):
    print(my_selector.select())
```

which gives:

```
('N3', 'N2')
('N5', 'N6')
('N4', 'N6')
('N1', 'N2')
('N4', 'N2')
('N5', 'N2')
('N7', 'N6')
('N3', 'N6')
('N7', 'N2')
('N1', 'N6')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<file>", line 35, in select
    index = self._sel_indices.pop()

IndexError: pop from empty list

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<file>", line 70, in <module>
    print(my_selector.select())

  File "<file>", line 40, in select
    raise RuntimeError("No more combinations to select") from ex
RuntimeError: No more combinations to select
```

You can catch a `RuntimeError` to prevent this traceback, or initialize the object with `raise_error=False` to re-shuffle and keep returning combinations, although these will be duplicates (but not in the same order as before):

```
my_selector = GroupedSelect(my_list, False)
for _ in range(12):
    print(my_selector.select())
```

outputs:

```
('N3', 'N2')
('N5', 'N6')
('N7', 'N2')
('N7', 'N6')
('N5', 'N2')
('N1', 'N2')
('N4', 'N6')
('N3', 'N6')
('N1', 'N6')
('N4', 'N2')
('N7', 'N6')
('N3', 'N6')
```

Comment: instead of `if c not in self.groups:
                self.groups[c] = []` you can call `self.groups.setdefault(c, []).append(n)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi
Is it efficient to separate a list into groups? The 2 samples I need from `my_list` will be 80 millions times. That is 80 millions of 2 samples.

Comment: @Viki The list is only separated into groups _once_. Every time you call `.select()`, we only need to select the elements from the groups we already created, so we aren't iterating over the entire million-long array.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you're absolutely right! I opted to use this approach to make it more clear what's going on in the grouping code.

Comment: @Viki I saw your edit to the question and addressed the requirement of unique combinations in my most recent edit. The logic for this is slightly more complicated than the first version of my answer because of the need to keep track of which combinations have already been selected. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
def pick_samples(all_choices):
    a = random.choice(all_choices)
    while True:
        b = random.choice(all_choices)
        if b[1] != a[1]:
            break
    return a[0], b[0]
```

If you're able, you can simplify by breaking the choices into two groups and choosing one from each:

```
c1_list = [c[0] for c in all_choices if c[1] == 'C1']
c2_list = [c[0] for c in all_choices if c[1] == 'C2']

def pick_samples(c1_list, c2_list):
    return random.choice(c1_list), random.choice(c2_list)
```

Comment: They apparently want to take 80 million samples